# how to redirect content of file to stdin, why the exec function doesn't work?

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, system-calls

I want to redirect a content of input.txt file to stdin.

I tried:

```
int RunCompiledFile(char *path, char * input, char *thirdLine, char* name){

    int fdFile = open(input, O_RDONLY), exitStatus, check,
    fdFileOutput = open("newOutput.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0777), status;
    char* args[] = {"comp.out", "newOutput.txt", thirdLine};
    char buffer[100];
    pid_t  pid;


    dup2(0, fdFile);
    dup2(fdFileOutput , 1);
    getcwd(buffer, 95);
    i = strlen(buffer);
    buffer[i] = '/';
    buffer[++i] = '\0';
    check = execv(buffer,"a.out");
    close(fdFileOutput);

    //if ((pid = fork()) == 0){
        check = execvp("comp.out", args);
      //  return 5;}

    wait(&status);
    exitStatus = WEXITSTATUS(status);

    switch (exitStatus){
        case 1:
            result("0", name, BADOUTPUT);
            unlink("newOutput.txt");
            return 1;
        case 2:
            if (depth){
                char buffer[5];
                sprintf(buffer, "%d", 100 - (10 * depth));
                result(buffer, name, WRONGDIRECTORY);}
            else
                result("100", name, GREATJOB);
                unlink("newOutput.txt");
            return 1;
        case 3:
            result("80", name, SIMILLAROUTPUT);
            unlink("newOutput.txt");
            return 1;
    }

    return fdFileOutput;
}
```

But becuase of all the forks it's hard to debbug.
the execv - after the "getcwd" returns -1.
a.out is a program the gets input via scanf(), and then does something and printf the answer.

I am supposed to get a file, turn it to stdin for the fgets of a.out,
and then open a new file for the output of a.out.

it's still doesn't work, I tried your fixes:

```
    dup2(fdFile, STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(fdFileOutput, STDOUT_FILENO);
    getcwd(buffer, 95);
    i = strlen(buffer);
    buffer[i] = '/';
    buffer[++i] = 'a';
    buffer[++i] = '.';
    buffer[++i] = 'o';
    buffer[++i] = 'u';
    buffer[++i] = 't';
    buffer[++i] = '\0';
    close(fdFileOutput);
    close(fdFile);
    check = execv(buffer,"a.out");
```

but the return from execv is still -1.
the a.out is working on different users (my friends tried it before).

Comment: Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please show your complete code and explain what problems you are having with that code.

Comment: I think it goes the other way around: `dup2( fd_input, STDIN_FILENO );`

Comment: First try to redirect a file without forks. Easier to debug, easier for ithers to help.

Comment: That is what I do now, and how I got the return of the exec.

Comment: What does `thirdLine` point to?

Comment: `exec` doesn't return if it succeeds, so if `exec` returned you have a bug in your program. In this case, the bug is that you passed the current-working-directory as the first argument to `execv`. The first argument to `execv` should be the full pathname of the executable file.

Comment: Your formatting stinks. You may want to adopt a better formatting style, perhaps resort those provided by IDEs.

Comment: Are you sure that a.out is an executable program. Have you tried its function independently and set the permissions ?

Comment: it has to be `int  check = execv("a.out",buffer);` according to this https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/execv.htm  `int execv(const char *file, char *const argv[]);`  and *a.out* has to be located in the same directory as the calling program.

Comment: buffer has the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

From [In C how do you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr to files when making an execvp() or similar call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543443/in-c-how-do-you-redirect-stdin-stdout-stderr-to-files-when-making-an-execvp-or):

*The right way to do it is to replace the file descriptors* `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO` *and* `STDERR_FILENO` *with the opened files using* `dup2()`. *You should also then close the original files in the child process:*

```
else if (pid == 0)
{
    dup2(fileno(someopenfile), STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(fileno(someotherfile), STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(fileno(somethirdopenfile), STDERR_FILENO);
    fclose(someopenfile);
    fclose(someotheropenfile);
    fclose(somethirdopenfile);
    execvp(args[0], args);
    // handle error ...
}
```

So open input and output files, create the childprocess (`fork()`) and then `dup2()` and rest of the code above

Beside this you can use `freopen()` ([Rerouting stdin and stdout from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584868/rerouting-stdin-and-stdout-from-c))

`freopen("newin", "r", stdin);` (without assignment to file handle [!])

These links are also interesting because they give information about the system functions like `fork()`, `dup2()`,...

[How to execute a shell script from C in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736210/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-from-c-in-linux)

[Bash: read stdin from file and write stdout to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680530/bash-read-stdin-from-file-and-write-stdout-to-file)

Comment: I can't use freopen(). I tried your fix - look up. and it's still returns -1.

Comment: It has to be **`int check = execv("a.out",buffer);`** not **`check = execv(buffer,"a.out");`** (https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/execv.htm) `int execv(const char *file, char *const argv[]);` and *a.out* has to be located in the same directory as the calling program or give the full path on your computer in the `execv()` command (at least now for testing), read this https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/execv.htm

Comment: Use a debugger (gdb)

Comment: I place the int check before (on the top).
I am using a debugger, that is how I know what returns from execvp

Comment: No, i mean that you have to change the ordering of the arguments  in the *execv* function **`int check = execv("a.out",buffer);`** not **`int check = execv(buffer,"a.out");`**. And give the full path (from root) to *a.out* on your computer in the execv-command. Have you ever tried to compile this try -v and -Wall options in the compiler and see the errors...

Comment: For debugging after a `fork()` see this https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html or seach engine with 'execv gdb' or 'fork gdb'

Comment: I am debugging with Code::blocks. 
I tried execv("a.out", buffer).
Still -1.

Comment: see this on how to use execv()  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575826/using-execv-c-language-to-run-commands-from-a-linux-command-prompt